# continue processing when web page loading is finished how can I do it?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

google web page loading, How can I do this after I install it? can I go to the next step?

```
 IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

      //page load then take action

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot get question completely But i assume you want to wait until page is fully loaded and then move to next element. You can try using implicit wait.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait();
```

If this doesn't help then you can add following JS sample

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, MyDefaultTimeout).Until(
d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor) d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```